# AcquireTokenAsync() raises cookiesdisabled error in login popup

Tags: wpf, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I am having an issue from a WPF (xbap) application with "Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL) Preview for .NET" that was all working until a windows update that changed something inside IE11, no code has changed.
My wpf app does work on some PC depending on the version of IE11?

These IE11 work:
PC1:
Version: 11.431.16299.0
Update Versions: 11.0.65 (KB4103768)

Server1:
Version: 11.2248.14393.0
Update Versions: 11.0.65 (KB4103768)

Server2:
Version: 11.0.9600.18638
Update Versions: 11.0.41 (KB40147661)

This doesnt work:
PC2 & PC3
Version: 11.48.17134.0
Update Versions: 11.0.65 (KB4103768)

Its weird as PC2/3 are on the same KB and update version as PC1, but the actual version is different.

I am using "Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL) Preview for .NET" and have tried 1.1.2 and 1.1.4 both fail in the same way.

I have tried the sample app inside "Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL) Preview for .NET" solution from GitHub and it works, its a desktop app.
As a test I moved the sample code into a new wpf xbap project and it fails with the same error error I get from my wpf app: [image]

I cant get into the browser/control that is used under the hood to call AcquireTokenAsync() so I cant work out how to make allow cookies.

Does anyone have any ideas on what else I could investigate/try that doesnt require changing the installed version of IE?

cheers
Craig

Comment: Just built a standard WPF desktop app using the sample code and it works fine as well, so its only the xbap version that fails.

Makes me think that the webbrowser being generated from the xbap is not the same webbrowser that is created by the others.

Comment: Did you enable cookies on the [browser](https://www.bing.com/search?q=set+browse+to+accept+cookies&form=EDGEAR&qs=PF&cvid=521edd526ba643ad8948defedc97391c&cc=US&setlang=en-US&redir=5&itrid=AA319353D82A4D52BAB38A24112BC5B0)?

Comment: Unfortunately you dont get access to the browser settings from inside the application. My IE11 has cookies enabled and works fine for AzureAD login.
its only an issuewhemn the browser is called from the xbap version of the WPF application

Comment: I am also having this issue, was a solution ever found?